# How do I map Spring MVC controller to a uri with and without trailing slash?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Controller with several RequestMappings for different URIs. My servlet is "ui". The servlet's base URI only works with a trailing slash. I would like my users to not have to enter the trailing slash.

This URI works:

```
http://localhost/myapp/ui/
```

This one does not:

```
http://localhost/myapp/ui
```

It gives me a HTTP Status 404 message.

The servlet and mapping from my web.xml are:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UiRootController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"","/"})
    public ModelAndView mainPage() { 
        DataModel model = initModel();
        model.setView("intro");     
        return new ModelAndView("main", "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/other"})
    public ModelAndView otherPage() { 
        DataModel model = initModel();
        model.setView("otherPage");     
        return new ModelAndView("other", "model", model);
    }

}
```

Comment: Change your url pattern in your web xml from /ui/* to /ui

Comment: @Sajan, I should have included the other RequestMappings. (See edit) Changing the pattern from /ui/* to /ui breaks all the mappings and I get 404 for URIs /ui, /ui/ and /ui/other

Comment: What context is the webapp deployed to in Tomcat? Is your application called `ROOT.war` or `<another_name>.war` or does the application just  exist in a directory under webapps?

Comment: @andyb, it is deployed to another context. In my example I use "myapp". Am I wrong to think this should work?

Comment: No, it definitely should work as expected. Which version of Spring are you using? Also, how are you configuring Spring, something like `<context:component-scan base-package="..."/>`?

Comment: Spring 3.1.2. Yep, got the component-scan scanning the appropriate package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your web application exists in the web server's webapps directory, for example `webapps/myapp/` then the root of this application context can be accessed at `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` assuming the default Tomcat port. This should work with or without the trailing slash, *I think* by default - certainly that is the case in Jetty v8.1.5

Once you hit `/myapp` the Spring [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) takes over, routing requests to the `<servlet-name>` as configured in your `web.xml`, which in your case is `/ui/*`.

The DispatcherServlet then routes all requests from `http://localhost/myapp/ui/` to the `@Controller`s.

In the *Controller* itself you can use **`@RequestMapping(value = "/*")`** for the *mainPage()* method, which will result in both `http://localhost/myapp/ui/` and `http://localhost/myapp/ui` being routed to *mainPage()*.

Note: you should also be using Spring >= v3.0.3 due to [SPR-7064](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7064)

For completeness, here are the files I tested this with:

#### src/main/java/controllers/UIRootController.java

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class UiRootController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/*")
  public ModelAndView mainPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("index");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value={"/other"})
  public ModelAndView otherPage() {
    return new ModelAndView("other");
  }
}
```

#### WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <!-- spring automatically discovers /WEB-INF/<servlet-name>-servlet.xml -->
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ui</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### WEB-INF/ui-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
  p:order="2"
  p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"
  p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/"
  p:suffix=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

And also 2 JSP files at `WEB-INF/views/index.jsp` and `WEB-INF/views/other.jsp`.

Result:

- `http://localhost/myapp/` -> directory listing
- `http://localhost/myapp/ui` and `http://localhost/myapp/ui/` -> index.jsp
- `http://localhost/myapp/ui/other` and `http://localhost/myapp/ui/other/` -> other.jsp

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 18):

Using Springboot, my app could reply both with and without trailing slash by setting @RequestMapping's "value" option to the empty string:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some")
public class SomeController {
//                  value = "/" (default) ,
//                  would limit valid url to that with trailing slash.
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Collection<Student> getAllStudents() {
        String msg = "getting all Students";
        out.println(msg);
        return StudentService.getAllStudents();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

> [PathMatchConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/PathMatchConfigurer.html) api allows you to configure various settings
>   related to URL mapping and path matching. As per the latest version of spring, trail path matching is enabled by default. For customization, check the below example.

**For Java-based configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
    }
}
```

**For XML-based configuration**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:path-matching trailing-slash="true"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

> *For @RequestMapping("/foo"), if trailing slash match set to **false**, example.com/foo/ != example.com/foo and if it's set to **true** (default), example.com/foo/ == example.com/foo*

Cheers!

Comment: Didn't know about this property. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I eventually added a new RequestMapping to redirect the /ui requests to /ui/.
Also removed the empty string mapping from the mainPage's RequestMapping.
No edit required to web.xml.

Ended up with something like this in my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/ui")
    public ModelAndView redirectToMainPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/ui/");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView mainPage() { 
        DataModel model = initModel();
        model.setView("intro");     
        return new ModelAndView("main", "model", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value={"/other"})
    public ModelAndView otherPage() { 
        DataModel model = initModel();
        model.setView("otherPage");     
        return new ModelAndView("other", "model", model);
    }
```

Now the URL `http://myhost/myapp/ui` redirects to `http://myhost/myapp/ui/` and then my controller displays the introductory page.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I found is to not give the request mapping for mainPage() a value:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView mainPage() { 
    DataModel model = initModel();
    model.setView("intro");     
    return new ModelAndView("main", "model", model);
}
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for mi so far, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try adding

`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list() {
        return "redirect:/strategy/list";
    }`

the result:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/strategy")
    public class StrategyController {
    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StrategyController.class);

    @Autowired
    private StrategyService strategyService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list() {
        return "redirect:/strategy/list";
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listOfStrategies(Model model) {
        logger.info("IN: Strategy/list-GET");

        List<Strategy> strategies = strategyService.getStrategies();
        model.addAttribute("strategies", strategies);

        // if there was an error in /add, we do not want to overwrite
        // the existing strategy object containing the errors.
        if (!model.containsAttribute("strategy")) {
            logger.info("Adding Strategy object to model");
            Strategy strategy = new Strategy();
            model.addAttribute("strategy", strategy);
        }
        return "strategy-list";
    }
```

** credits:

[Advanced @RequestMapping tricks – Controller root and URI Template](http://duckranger.com/2012/04/advanced-requestmapping-tricks-controller-root-and-uri-templates/)

Comment: *Advanced @RequestMapping tricks* - This is a broken link. Plz update the new one or remove the link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the ideal approach, but what worked for me was to treat them as if they were **two different paths** and make them **both accepted** by each of my endpoints, such as.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/mb/actor")
public class ActorController {

@GetMapping({"", "/"})
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllActors() {

    ...
}

@GetMapping({"/{actorId}", "/{actorId}/"})
public ResponseEntity<Object> getActor(@PathVariable UUID actorId) {

    ...
}
```

There may be best ways to do this and to avoid this duplication, and I'd love to know that. However, what I found when I tried using `configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);` is that ***broken paths*** also start becoming accepted, such as `/api/mb////actor` (with many slashs), and that's why I ended up going the multiple paths instead.