# Java Spring MVC application accepts POST requests only with trailing slash

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC application with following details

1. war file name is forms.war. url pattern in web.xml is`"/"`
2. Controller action's @RequestMapping is `"/"`
3. RequestMethod.GET actions work properly if localhost:8080/forms is hit
4. RequestMethod.POST actions not triggered if the post data is hit against `localhost:8080/forms`
5. The POST requests gives a 302 redirect
6. When I hit `localhost:8080/forms/` the POST requests work properly

Any solution to make POST request work without trailing slash?

Here is the code I used to test the POST api:

```
public class HttpPostExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        try {

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/forms");
            StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"form_url\":\"admin\",\"website\":\"US_WEBSITE\",\"email\":\"testelascrip1@gmail.com\",\"cis_name\":\"testscrip1\"} ");
            request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            System.out.println("Printing the response code " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Changing the url to /forms/ works for POST request but not /forms

Comment: could you add the controller code?

Comment: probably the difference its because in the GET request you are not sending parameters, so doesnt mind you add or not the slash, but in the POST you will add some parameters, and you need to add a proper URL action to attach all parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I map Spring MVC controller to a uri with and without trailing slash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043618/how-do-i-map-spring-mvc-controller-to-a-uri-with-and-without-trailing-slash)

Comment: You can control this behavior globally by using `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(boolean)`. Have you set this to false somewhere?

Comment: @cralfaro here is the controller code
<code>
\@Controller
public class JSONController {

 \@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public \@ResponseBody 
 String handleGET(HttpServletRequest request) {
 }
 
 \@RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public \@ResponseBody
 String handlePOST(HttpServletRequest request) {
 }
}
</code>

Comment: am sorry about the formatting

Comment: @john16384 yes but tried all the solutions there. didn't work.

Comment: @AnsgarSchulte No. I have not set that to false anywhere.

Comment: @ElavarasuPandiyan can you add to your question (Edit it) the form where are you calling the POST method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `@RequestMapping` to either no mapping (so don't put a value at all not even `"/"`) or to `"/*"`.

Comment: Tried both. Didn't work. Like not even having the value in RequestMapping and also the value "/*".

Comment: The GET requests work fine as per the link you have shared.
What am facing issue is with the POST request. It just gets a 302. But the POST request with /forms/ works fine.