# Controller doesn't work with spring

Tags: java, spring, controller

I use spring mvc with spring configuration (without xml). And it seems like IDEA doesn't go to controller code. Maybe somewhere path is incorrect so @RequestMapping doesn't work. But i can't understand where exactly.
Here is my Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {

        return "index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(Model m){
        m.addAttribute("name","lol kkeke");
        return "index2";
    }
}
```

WebMvcConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.chat")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/styles/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/fonts/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/views/");

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();

    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("/index.jsp");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your MainController is under com.chat package?

Comment: com.chat.controller - mainController; 
com.chat.config - webmvcConfig

Comment: Change mapping to start from / like  this `@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)`

Comment: Are you sure the configuration is even loaded? Spring usually requires a XML file with at least configuration for the annotation scanning. That or the usage of something like Spring Boot.

Comment: i'm almost sure. From 3.0 version we may configure only by java-classes.(pom.xml must be)

Comment: Sranislav, yep,i change but problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. I solved a problem. It was in Controller - path. My Idea automatically change path from com.chat.controller to c.c.controller. So i rebuild project structure to   com.chat.controller.Controller.class;   and com.chat.config.Configuration.class.

Also, i found the next article about similar trouble. May be it will help somebody! [How do I map Spring MVC controller to a uri with and without trailing slash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043618/how-do-i-map-spring-mvc-controller-to-a-uri-with-and-without-trailing-slash)