# Prevent embedded Tomcat from redirecting requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, tomcat8

I have Spring boot-starter-web application with a bunch of RestControllers. It seems that Spring, by default, has some mechanism to redirect requests without a trailing slash to the same request *with* a trailing slash. So, the following request:

```
GET http://server/context-name
```

results in a 302 response with the following location header:

```
Location: http://server/context-name/
```

Is there a way to disable this behaviour? I would be happy with a 404 response, but I do not want a redirect.

**EDIT:** After some research I found out that it's probably Tomcat that is doing the redirect. In a standalone Tomcat this behaviour can be configured with `mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled` ([see Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html)) but I can't figure out how to do this for an embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Use `PathMatchConfigurer$setUseTrailingSlashMatchAnswer()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45258671/5873923).

Comment: That option allows to map "/context/users" to "/context/users/" but doesn't prevent Spring from redirecting "/context" to "/context/".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by changing

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

to

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

It was nothing to do with Spring or Tomcat though there are options for both that looks close.

Hope this can help.